# Network Error Unable to reach the server when trying to expand search

Tags: error, search-results

using Civi 5.14 on WordPress 5.2

We are getting a ***Network Error Unable to reach the server*** error when attempting to go to page 2 of a search list.  I have read the other posts and checked what they suggested. The console only shows ***"JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1"*** It doesn't indicate that this is wrong.  Am I missing something?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have anything in log?

Comment: There is nothing in the logs since 7/31

Comment: Can you check CiviCRM resource url? Also in console network tab can you check the link on which its throwing this error?

Comment: the resource url is https://secure.domain.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm   The console network tab isn't showing any errors.  The link goes to a blank php page  https://secure.domain.org/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

Comment: Could you check "log XMLhttprequests" and see what's the url fetched when you click next?

Comment: I have no idea what that is or where to check it.